# Discord.js Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm adding some new things to a discord.js bot I made about a year ago.
I have made a json file `botconfigs.json` which looks like this:

```
{"641702354579881994":{"prefix":"$","modLogsChannel":643786173285924864}}
```

I have a file purge.js that deletes the messages in a channel and I want to send an embed to the channel specified in the JSON file. When I do `console.log(botconfigs[guildid].modLogsChannel);` It prints out the channel id as it should. When I do `bot.channels.get(botconfigs[guildid].modLogsChannel).send({embed: purgeEmbed});` it says:

> Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Full Code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const botconfigs = require("../botconfigs.json");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    if(message.member.roles.some(r=>["Owner", "Co-Owner", "Manager", "Build Manager", "Development Manager", "Administrator", "Senior Builder", "Senior Developer", "Moderator+", "Builder+", "Developer+"].includes(r.name)) ) {
        const amount = args[0];
        if (!amount) return message.reply('You must specify an amount to delete! (Min: 2 Max: 100)');
        if (amount > 100) return message.reply('Specified amount too large! (Max: 100)');
        if (amount < 2) return message.reply('Specified amount too small! (Min: 2)');
        let guildid = message.guild.id;
        message.channel.fetchMessages({
        limit: 100,
        }).then((messages) => {
        message.channel.bulkDelete(amount).catch(error => console.log(error.stack));

        let purgeEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor("#00001")
        .setAuthor("HN Modlogs")
        .addField("Moderation:", "Purge", true)
        .addField("Messages Deleted:", amount, true)
        .setThumbnail(bot.user.displayAvatarURL)
        .addField("Moderator:", message.author.username, true)

        bot.channels.get(botconfigs[guildid].modLogsChannel).send({embed: purgeEmbed});
 });
  } else {
    return message.channel.send("You don't have permission to use this command!");
 }
}

module.exports.config = {
  name: "purge",
  usage: "u.purge <messageCount>",
  description: "Deletes Lots Of Messages (MAX 100).",
}
```

Originally I used `bot.guilds.get('641702354579881994').channels.get('643786173285924864').send({embed: purgeEmbed});` and it worked perfectly. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Specifying a guild first might help ex:

```js
bot.guilds.get(guildid)
  .channels.get(botconfigs[guildid].modLogsChannel)
  .send({embed: purgeEmbed});
```

Comment: Tried using that before too, same result.

Comment: Are you sure `botconfigs[guildid].modLogsChannel` is a string? Only strings will work.

Comment: Yeah, I'm guessing it is a number.

Comment: It is a number. Do I have to put it in quotation marks in json file?

Comment: Yes, in discord.js an id needs to be a string, otherwise `.get()` will return undefined.